# How do I get Chrome Devtools to sort scope properties alphabetically?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Chrome devtools used to display properties in the "scope" pane in alphabetical order for me. For example, see the screenshot here about "scope in Sources tab in Google Chrome": https://dev.to/shadowwarior5/understanding-javascript-scope-41m2

However, here's what I'm seeing now:
[Chrome Devtools Global Scope Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPo80.png)

Anyone know how to get it to sort alphabetically? Anyone else seeing this behavior? Searches on SO and Google turn up nothing on this (except to say that it does sort alphabetically for your convenience).

I'm seeing this on multiple computers, both Windows and MacOS, and I don't have any plugins or anything installed.

I'm running Chrome Version 79.0.3945.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
It seems the issue is fixed in the 83.0.4103.11 version:

http://prnt.sc/t5hhci

Old answer:

I also encountered that problem. Until they fix it, I decided to downgrade the previous Chrome version I had (which was 75.0.3770.80).

You can download old versions of Chrome here:
https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

Comment: I downgraded to the previous version I had, 75.0.3770.80:
https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Chrome 80.0.3987.100 and I'm also experiencing the same issue -- all the object properties are no longer in alphabetical order which is very annoying.

I did not find any option to change this behaviour in the developer settings for preferences.

I've submitted to chromium bugs:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1052176